# Paths relative to the file location and NOT the url

Tags: html, dynamic, friendly-url

**** EDIT: SOLVED HERE [Relative paths from file for img, a and header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697601/relative-paths-from-file-for-img-a-and-header) ****

Somewhat new to web design.

I just finished creating a dynamic site. It can read domain/category, domain/category/this-article-about-x, all redirecting to domain/index.php and working well.

However, I quickly learned that whenever I used a relative path such as ./include, the relative path was taking in account the current URL, and not the actual url where the php file is at.

I have 2 questions that I couldn't answer when browsing the internet for a long time:

1) If domain/index.php is trying to show an image with ./thumbnails/science/image.jpg, it won't work if the actual url is domain/category/, but it WILL work if its just domain/category(no slash at the end). Why this inconsistency? The HTML code is showing the src to the image is the same on both cases.

2) My header has a dropdown menu with categories. Once its submitted, it will call itself (header.php), see which category the user chose and redirect to domain/category. All works well. You can then rechange the dropdown menu to another category and everything loads again. But again, if you access directly domain/cateory/ (with the slash at the end), the CSS won't load, the images won't load as said on question 1, and submitting the form will cause a problem because it will look for header.php on domain/category/, and not just on domain where the header.php file actually is.

I have successfully used dirname(**FILE**) to make sure my includes all work (as far as my testing has gone, no errors). But I could not use dirname(**FILE**) to generate links or images 'img src=' that will always point to the images regardless of the URL.

On localhost, the HTML is coming as img src=c:\path\htdocs\thumbnails\img, which is right, but the image does not display anyway. Same with the 'a href' links. Trying to create links with dirname(**FILE**) created links on localhost as c:\correctpath, but clicking on them did absolutely nothing. Also, using header with dirname(**FILE**) to handle the redirection from the dropdown menu caused it to cease working as well (but if I used ./ . dropDownMenuValue, it would again correctly change the url to domain/categoryChosen)

How can I use a consistent method for relative urls that allow me to work on localhost and then upload to my web host without the need make changes to the files, AND that works with dynamic websites that have pretty name urls through htaccess?

Thank you,

This is all very puzzling for me how getting a relative path from the current file path is being so hard and generating so many different issues, and why only include statements seem to work well with dirname(**FILE**)

Edit: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10374336-RESOLVED-mod_rewrite-for-SEO-Friendly-URLs-and-relative-path-issue-fixes

I've found this on other sites, but it requires you to change the base everytime you want to go from localhost to the web. I'm trying to avoid that. Clearly there has to be a simple way to do something so basic. I can't believe google and everybody else are changing paths when they are ready to make something live.

Comment: You hit on one of the key words into your title. You should do some searching on SO for absolute vs relative URLs.

Comment: I did, but every link I found said to use relative urls as in ./, which doesn't work with dynamic websites with pretty urls. I'm looking for a solution to that, to use relative paths with htaccess based pretty-urls specifically when dealing with IMG, A HREF and Header.

Comment: For dynamic websites, you should place all of the folders for the `css`, `js`, `images`, etc. in the web root, so you can access everything with absolute URLs like `/css`, `/js`, `/images`, etc.

Comment: It doesn't work phpmycoder, that is my point. A simple <link href='/CSS/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> will break if you access the site through root/categories/ (but not if you dont add the slash at the end, which I'm tyring to get an answer too)

Comment: What is the absolute path of the css folder?

Comment: on localhost its c:\path\htdocs\site\CSS, on the web is public_html\sitename\CSS or domain\CSS

Comment: Can you place the CSS folder in the web root, so it can be accessed without the sitename or domain directory?

Comment: it is, but you can't acess it because when you are using a pretty url like root/categories/article, using /css won't work. It will be read as root/categories/article/css

Answer (score 0):

You should just always use absolute paths for public files like media.  If you don't want to do that for some reason or your site is just too involved at this point you'll have to create rewrite rules for the other file types so they can also be included from the correct path.

Comment: How can you make rewrite rules when you have this scenario:

1) Index.php at root handles all 'img src' on the page
2) if you access root it works, but if you access root/category/article, it wont work again because the relative path will be going from root/category/article and not just root

are you saying I should have rewrite rules for /category/ and /category article for the images, is that it? And then also for the forms, and what about the PHP header that does not work with dirname(__FILE__)?

Comment: The redirecting using a relative path is more complicated; `dirname(__FILE__)` is probably something like `/srv/http/path/to/website/` so that's just not going to work at all.  As for `img src` that will respect rewrite rules just fine; it would be the same as going to the image URL directly.  Don't use relative paths!  They're evil.

Comment: Why are relative paths evil? 

Also, redirecting is not really a choice it seems.

I can have a rule that redirects domain/category/article, but my problem is that depending on where you are accessing the site, I'm having urls being written as domain/category/categoryagain/something. 

My whole issue is this.

Comment: You're experiencing why relative paths are evil right now, aren't you?

Comment: I'm experiencing relative paths from the URL.

They are good if I actually write a relative path from the file

Comment: I'm very confused .. can you give me a specific img src that you would like to use?  Where is the image actually located on the disk and what is the `src` attribute, for example?

Comment: img path is root/thumbnails/img
Now I want to generate the 'img src' for the img from index.php which is on the root folder. So far so good.

The problem happens when I need to generate img from root/category/article (which htaccess translates to root/index.php?categry=x&article=y)

Now my 'img src' will be relative to category/article if I use ./, and if I use dirname(FILE), I get the src to c:\correctpath, but the image still doesn't displays

Comment: And my CSS wont load if I access through root/category/, but will if I do through root/category, without the slash, which is odd. No idea why this happens.

Comment: paths on the disk are totally different from paths on the website.  Where is the document root on the disk?

Comment: the document root on the disk is c:\folders\htdocs, on the web is a shared host so its ~username\public_html\addon_domain

Comment: That doesn't make sense .. is ~username\public_html\addon_domain a shortcut or something?

Comment: no, its my shared hosts on hostgator. Of course I access it through registered domain names, but the root folder is not pointing to the root folder of my site, since my site is an addon-domain

Comment: The "document root" is the path on the disk where the website is.  For example, `/srv/http`.  So `/srv/http/folder/index.php` would be accessed by `http://example.com/folder/index.php`.  All image/js/css paths need to be relative to the document root, not the path on the disk.

Comment: yes but since my localhost and web host have different document roots for all my websites, I want to use relative paths so I don't have to change adressess all the time

Comment: You don't need to do that as long as the img/js/css is in the same place *relative to the document root*.  Just use an absolute path (but not a url).  For example, `/images/image.png` will work on both websites (it's an absolute path; the server knows to use the document root to find it on the disk in both cases).

Comment: doesn't work, not even the CSS works when i access domain/prettyurl/pretturl, the css brakes

Comment: What is your server configuration like?  Are you sure you're not preventing it from serving files requested normally?